# ASSERT_THROW thinks my exception is of a different type

Tags: c++, googletest

In Google Test, when I run the following test:

```
void ThrowInvalidArgument()
{
   throw new std::invalid_argument("I am thrown an invalid_argument");
}

TEST(ExpectExceptions, Negative)
{
  ASSERT_THROW(ThrowInvalidArgument(), std::invalid_argument);
}
```

I get the following failure:

```
error: Expected: ThrowInvalidArgument() throws an exception
                 of type std::invalid_argument.
       Actual: it throws a different type.
[  FAILED  ] ExpectExceptions.Negative (1 ms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are throwing an instance of the `std::invalid_argument*` type, that is, *a pointer*.

Throw an object instead:

```
void ThrowInvalidArgument()
{
     throw std::invalid_argument("I am thrown an invalid_argument");
     //   ^ (no new)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To extend on Pjotr's valid answer: Exceptions always should be thrown from plain temporary instances and caught as const references:

```
void ThrowInvalidArgument() {
    throw std::invalid_argument("I am thrown an invalid_argument");
}

void Elsewhere {
    try {
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument& invalidArgEx) {
    }
}
```

Comment: ... unless you plan o modify the exception and rethrow it, in which case an un-const refreence is in order.   catch(MyException & ex){ ex.addContextInformation(..this info will help diagnose the problem...); throw; }

Comment: @DaleWilson I'd consider doing so bad design in 1st place. Though there might be valid use cases, I didn't come over one the last 30 yrs :P.